# Update with a minimum value from a union in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update, min, union-all

```
UPDATE table1 t SET t.columnA =
(SELECT MIN(columnB) FROM
    (SELECT columnB FROM table2
    WHERE table2.fk = t.pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT columnB FROM table3
    WHERE table3.fk = t.pk))
```

gives me `ORA-00904: "T"."PK": invalid identifier` . Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of scoping.  Oracle does not recognize the outer query alias more than one level of nesting deep.

If we assume that values are in both tables, then you can use `LEAST()` with subqueries:

```
UPDATE table1 t
    SET t.columnA =  LEAST( (SELECT MIN(columnB)
                             FROM table2
                             WHERE table2.fk = t.pk
                            ),
                            (SELECT MIN(columnB)
                             FROM table3
                             WHERE table2.fk = t.pk
                            )
                          );
```

If not, you can modify your query by moving the correlation clause out one level:

```
UPDATE table1 t
    SET t.columnA = (SELECT MIN(columnB)
                     FROM ((SELECT table2.fk, columnB FROM table2
                           ) UNION ALL
                           (SELECT table3.fk, columnB FROM table3
                           )
                          ) tt
                     WHERE tt.fk = t.pk
                    );
```

Comment: The second one is what I needed. Why did I not think of that? :) Thanks a lot.